# What should I do instead of modifying computed property?

Tags: vue.js, vue-reactivity

`computed(() => ...)` properties in Vue (3) are not deeply reactive. According to this [comment on github](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/8183#issuecomment-388818806), "computed properties are considered immutable and should never be mutated directly".

I wonder how much sense that makes in a framework that embraces the concept of "magical, unseen reactivity" the way Vue does?

It's more or less the same issue I have with props being considered immutable. Let me explain:

In my current project, I have a fairly complex, recursive data structure, which I need to visualize. Let's assume it looks like this:

```js
interface Datastructure {
  name: string;
  key: string;
  selected: boolean;
  value: number | undefined;
  properties: {
    name: string;
    value: number | undefined;
    selected: boolean
  }[];
  nested: Datastructure[];
}
```

What I do is have a bunch of components, roughly

```
DataElement.vue // visualize and edit name and selected
  |- Property.vue // visualize and edit property values
  |- Property.vue
  |- ...
  |-DataList.vue // go to next nested element, repeat
      |- DataElement.vue
      |   |- ...
      |- DataElement.vue
      |- ...
```

If I did this *cleanly*, meaning *immutably*, you can imagine the terrible amount of events I'd need to fire up the component tree, or the complexity of the store from which I pull this data.

Instead, I can just wrap the top level `Datastructure` in `reactive`, throw that down the component tree and happily mutate away.

I have some additional complexity that means sometimes selections are made based on other data, so typically what I do for now is something like

```js
const withOnlyShownChildDataElements = computed(
  () => reactive(
    removeNonSelectedChildren(props.dataElement, someReactiveSelectorThing)
  )
);
```

and then I use that to create child elements.

I come from Angular and RxJS, so I *do see* that this is kinda ugly. But it works just marvellously! Still, I wonder if I'm not missing something. In the world of `reactive(...)`, why is this still considered bad style?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. Deep reactivity and immutability are different concepts, one does not imply the other. And I believe computeds are deep reactive. If you want mutable computeds, have a look at [writable computed](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/computed.html#writable-computed). IMO, returning a `reactive()` from a computed does not makes sense since computeds are refs, so you could just return a plain object, and conceptually, reactive objects are used to track changes over time, you generally don't replace them. Please clarify if I am missing what you are asking

Comment: @MoritzRingler no, computed properties are not deeply reactive. You are right about the different concepts. So, why does Vue embrace the concept of deep reactivity in most places, but then the concept of immutability when crossing component borders? Or, in short, is, what I describe above bad style? If so, how to do better?

Comment: You're misusing a computed, there are watchers for fine-grained reactivity. Regular computeds are read-only. You could think of them as of observables in terms of Rx. And then there are writable computeds which you could overlook, those are the subjects. "what I do for now is something like" - reactive inside computed shouldn't happen. It's unclear how did you end up with computeds at all, the question doesn't reflect your case. Datastructure looks like a case for global store. But even if it's local state, partial changes could be handled with writable computeds.

Comment: @EstusFlask I'm thinking along the same lines as you, but I do wonder how basically re-building a computed with a watcher is going to make an actual difference? At the end of the day, `computed(() => reactive(...))` expresses precisely what I want to do...

Comment: Changing a ref inside a watcher would be the way it's idiomatically done in Vue. I don't remember if there are performance or other implications of doing `computed(() => reactive(` but there may be.